How am I wiring my new GFCI receptacle wrong?
I am trying to replace an outlet receptacle under my sink with a GFCI receptacle. I have two sets of wires, each with a black, white, and ground wire. I used a multimeter to determine that the black wire on the left of the photo (coming up from the cabinet floor) was receiving current with the circuit on. None of the other wires were hot. I then turned off the circuit for installation.
I'll mention here that sadly the last receptacle (which was non-GFCI in metal housing—yikes) was torn out my brother-in-law during kitchen reno before I had a chance to get a clear picture of the wiring, so it's difficult to ascertain what was going on with the circuit before or if it was even working properly.
Moving to install, I attached the hot black wire and its corresponding neutral white wire to the “line” terminals on the GFCI outlet, and then attached the other wires (coming from the wall) to the “load” terminals. I also attached the ground wires to the ground screw via pigtail (which is why they're in a wire nut now). When I turn on the circuit, the outlet doesn’t get power, even when I flip the corresponding wall switch. What am I doing wrong?
(FWIW, I also tried flipping the line and load and the green light on my GFCI receptacle turned on but the outlet still wasn't delivering power. I suspect this is because the current was "balanced" so the GFCI thought it was working properly but without any power going to the line terminal, the receptacle delivered no power. Someone please correct me if I am wrong).


Did you confirm that the GFCI receptacle was reset after installation? By the way, there's nothing inherently wrong about a non-GFCI receptacle in a metal junction box. No need to be worried over that.

Where this went off the rails was thinking you were obliged to use the Load terminals for any onward wires.  That is widely believed, but it is wrong.  Load should never be used except to provide GFCI protection to the downline, and the downline outlets should be known and labeled "GFCI protected".  I suggest also with the location of the reset.

Turns out the second cable was indeed a dead-end switch loop. Following instructions from another forum, I wired the receptacle as follows:
Feed cable: White wire goes to Neutral line side terminal on your GFCI. Black wire gets nutted to white wire on switch cable.
Switch cable: White wire is nutted to black feed already. Black wire goes to Hot line side terminal on your GFCI.
Ground gets pigtailed through, ground the GFCI.
This works as intended!

Good, but this answer was already provided. Please take the [tour] to learn how you should've instead responded.

If one of the cables is a switch loop and one is a line hot and its neutral, then the latter should be connected to the line side of the GFCI and it should work. The switch loop cable (B, W , bare copper) should not be connected to anything. Just tape or cap the ends. Or just pull the switch loop cable out of the box and curl it up.

Note that some GFCI receptacles do not like having power to them interrrupted, and will nuisance trip.  In that case just use another brand.

With GFCI (whether new or replacement), always:

Connect just the line side hot/neutral
Turn on power and test
Make sure TEST/RESET work correctly

After all that is confirmed good, then you turn off power, connect the load side hot/neutral and then turn on power and try again. If the GFCI either doesn't power up or powers up and immediately trips then you have a few possibilities:

The load side hot/neutral has a ground fault - the very thing that GFCIs are designed to protect
The load side hot/neutral is actually something else, such as a switch loop. In your particular case, I don't think that is what is going on, but hard to say without knowing where that cable goes.

But as far as:

*which was non-GFCI in metal housing—yikes

Assuming by metal housing you mean "metal junction box", that is actually a good thing. Why? Because metal boxes have lots of advantages over plastic boxes. In particular, a metal box automatically grounds switches and good quality receptacles via the metal yoke (the incoming ground wires go to screws in the box instead of to the devices) and a loose hot wire in a plastic box is actually more of a danger than in a metal box because in a metal box once it touches the metal it will trip the circuit breaker.
I would even suggest replacing this plastic box under the sink with a metal box.

Ah good to know! Yes, I did mean a metal junction box. I actually got this outdoor plastic box only because I was having trouble finding an indoor box with mounting "wings" at the "back" in my local HD/Lowes.
FWIW, the receptacle does work properly when wired as you suggested (with just the line side hot and neutral). When I turn off the circuit for this particular wire, nothing else in my entire kitchen (or indeed house) loses power. So I do think the other cable is simply a switch loop. But not sure how to wire that properly.

A switch loop would mean that there is (or was) a switch controlling either one or both of the outlets in the original receptacle. So if you have a switch - e.g., for a disposal, which is common for an undersink receptacle - that doesn't do anything, that makes sense. Otherwise I would expect a chain to another receptacle makes more sense. But hard to tell. The cable must go...somewhere.

@JimStewart Thank you. Corrected.

I suspect that your second cable is actually a switch loop and not a cable that goes on to feed other outlets.  In practice, that means that power comes into your box on one cable, is sent through to a switch on one wire, comes back on the second wire, and connects back to the "hot" side of your receptacle.  The neutral from the panel does as expected and goes to the "line" neutral terminal.
Here's a basic diagram that shows the concept:

If you have a continuity tester, you can verify this hypothesis by testing between the two wires on your "upper" cable.  It should beep (or light up) when your switch is on, and stop when it is off.

I don't have a continuity tester, but I think you're right about the switch loop. Especially because the receptacle does work with just the line terminals hooked up the hot and neutral from the "lower" cable.

OP says he has a "multimeter". These usually are VOM (volt, ohm, milliammeter). The ohm mode is used to test continuity. But be careful that the circuit is not energized when you are in ohm mode or milliamp mode. An energized circuit will blow an internal fuse in a multimeter in ohm or amp mode.

A duplex receptacle under a sink nearly always has at least one of the two receptacles switched to use the switch to control a disposer. In a superior installation one receptacle of the duplex is switched hot and the other receptacle is a line hot (always hot and not affected by the switch. But often the both of the receptacles are wired with the same switched hot. What do you want to use this under sink receptacle for? Is there a wall switch above the counter near the sink?
